# use a variable multiple times in a sql statement with pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

[edit: removed the where statement]

I'm trying to update a table when duplicate keys are passed in
I have a list like

```
examplelist = [[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [key3, value3]]
```

and a table with, for example, `key1` and `key3` already in the table with different values, so we want to update those rows and insert the key/value pair key2 value2 in. The table was created with:

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE exampletable (keycolumn FLOAT, valuecolumn FLOAT)')
cursor.execute('CREATE INDEX keycolumn_index ON exampletable (keycolumn DESC)')
```

I was trying to use

```
sql = "INSERT INTO exampletable (keycolumn, valuecolumn) VALUES (%s, %s)"\
" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE valuecolumn = VALUES(valuecolumn)"
cursor.executemany(sql, examplelist)
```

but I get a bunch of rows with the same keycolumn value

I can just change the input to a list of 3 element lists but this seems really sloppy, I imagine there's a more elegant way

Comment: INSERT query syntax does not contain WHERE clause. Study: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html The query may contain WHERE only as a part of SELECT query which is a datasource for INSERT query.

Comment: You don't have to tell it which is the key, that's determined automatically from the table definition. The key column is any set of columns with a unique index. This includes the primary key.

Comment: I shouldn't have put that where clause in, it was an attempt to fix my problem that wasn't working anyway. Took it out and left the original issue (duplicate "key"s)

Comment: whoa whats with the close votes? I'm editing the question to fix the problem, isn't that the preferred route?

Comment: as "cannot be reproduced"? seriously? you can reproduce that error easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using `float` type for the index. This leads to unpredictable behavior as equality checking doesn't work well for float types.
use something like `DECIMAL(total_precision, decimal_precision)` for the key type instead.

Also, the query can be simplified to initialize the key on declaring the table.

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE exampletable (keycolumn DECIMAL(10,2) PRIMARY KEY, valuecolumn DECIMAL(10,2))')
```